# how to test ajax response using jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine

I am new to jasmine.
I am looking for a way to check if one particular node is present in the ajax response. I am running jasmine command line using grunt. I am able to check if a function is called after success Ajax call. My code looks like this.

```
describe("Ajax call test.", function () {
    it("should execute the callback function on success", function () {
        spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function(options) {
            options.success();
        });
        var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
        getSampleResponse( callback);
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    function getSampleResponse(callback){
        $.ajax({url: "template/sample.json", dataType:"text", success:function(res){            
            callback();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My sample.json file looks like this.

```
{
   success: {

    "numSearches":5,
    "data":[
        {title:'search title 1', count:1},
        {title:'search title 2', count:1},
        {title:'search title 3', count:1},
        {title:'search title 4', count:1},
        {title:'search title 5', count:1}
    ]

  } 
}
```

I want to check if the response contains success.numSearches.
how can i do this using jasmine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh,

You have already stubbed out the actual ajax call with a mock. Are you looking to test your mock response for numSearches?

In your success call, you are not passing the json response `res` to your callback method.

Here is a good article to test ajax calls in Jasmine
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/testing-ajax-event-handlers-using-jasmine-spies.html

One way to test your ajax response is

`describe("Ajax call test.", function () {
    it("should execute the callback function on success", function () {
       var callbackCalled = false;
       function myCallback(jsonData) {
           callbackCalled = true;
           expect(jsonData.numSearches).toBeEqual(5);
       }
       getSampleResponse(myCallback);
       expect(callbackCalled).toBeTruthy();
    });`

```
function getSampleResponse(callback){
    $.ajax({url: "template/sample.json", dataType:"text", success:function(res){            
        callback(res);
        }
    });
}
```

});`

Please note, I added `res` as parameter to your callback method

Comment: I did not found any solution for asynchronous ajax callback data. So i was trying like this to at least get the success function has been called. I am able to test ajax call by adding async:false in the $.ajax which makes the spec to wait till it completes. Just not able to find the way to test async ajax response.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but got error:
Error: callback() method does not exist in file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/tes
tCase/.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine.js (line 1992) (1)

Then i tried adding window.callback = function(){};
Then getting this eror.
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.callback.mostRe
centCall.args') in file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/testCase/spec/domSpec.js (line 50)
 
If you can try and see if it works for you will be really helpful. 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, try the new implementation.  I missed that you were actually passing in the callback method

Comment: Actual ajax call in a unit test is probably not good as a practice.  You would want to test the actual service call in an integration test to keep your unit tests running fast and efficient

Comment: this does not work. This way it does not wait for ajax response it seems.
  Expected false to be truthy. (1)

You may be right in terms of keeping the test running fast.
But i may keep a unit test file which will have all ajax call spec to check if server gives proper response. Any other suggestions ?